# Referencing files within an iPad Application

Tags: ipad, sqlite

I'm developing an iPad App & currently testing it on the device itself - I'm using an sqlite database to read in the urls of .m4v movie files.

For testing using the simulator I list urls in the database as follows:

```
/Users/Octave1/Desktop/iDev/Moodymann/IMM Simulator App/Content/Movies/visuals seg0.m4v
.
.
.
```

This works fine & the database is read correctly, & the files play as required.

When I run the App on the iPad I change the urls in the database to the following format:

```
/Content/Movies/visuals seg0.m4v
.
.
.
```

However the movie doesn't play at all. It seems like there is a problem with the path & that the files aren't being found - anyone know the correct way to reference files *within* the Application itself?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, for anyone with the same issue.

First of all - I copied my "Content" folder over to the iPad, placing it in the Library Directory, as follows:

```
//Finding out where the Library Directory is located
NSString *libraryDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
//Find where my content folder is initially
NSString *contentPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Content"];

NSError *error = nil;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:contentPath 
                                        toPath:libraryDirectory
                                         error:&error];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:contentPath toPath:folderPath error:&error]){
    NSLog(@"File successfully copied");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error description-%@ \n", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Error reason-%@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

I can then read out the address of each movie, & append each address to the address of the libarary

```
NSString *inFilePath = movieObj.pathToMovie; ///Content/Movies/visuals seg0.m4v from above  
NSLog(@"inFilePath is: %@", inFilePath);
NSString *fullPath = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:inFilePath]];                   
NSLog(@"fullPath is: %@", fullPath);

            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:fullPath];      
            NSLog(@"url is: %@", url);
            [movieUrlArray addObject:url];
```

Now I know the urls of the movie files, within the Application's file system.